# Prove that every element of the complex numbers is unit.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This is how I attempted to prove this, but I am almost certain I have done it wrong because I assumed far too much.
I said: since we know by definition that the complex numbers are a field, and we know by definition that there exists a nonzero number b in a field F such that for every nonzero a in F, ab=1. So since this is true for all fields, that means all elements in the complex numbers have an inverse and therefore, every element of the complex numbers is unit.

Comment: I suspect you're supposed to show that $\mathbb{C} = \{a + bi \mid a, b \in \mathbb{R} \}$ where $i$ is the imaginary unit, actually *is* a field.

Comment: Yeah, I would imagine that is what I should do. Do you have a suggestion on how to do that?

Comment: Explicitly constructing an inverse to $a + bi$ isn't much work, so that's a quick way of doing it.

Comment: $0\in\mathbb C$ is not a unit ... And it's _definitely_ not true that "there exists a nonzero number b in a field F such that for every nonzero a in F, ab=1". (Hm, yes it is: take $F=\mathbb F_2$ and $b=1$. But that doesn't tell you anything about $\mathbb C$).

Comment: So the inverse would be (a+bi)/(a^2+b^2) but since a and b are both arbitrary numbers, this is essentially just a+bi and therefore, a number a+bi exists such that that number multiplied by any element of the complex numbers = 1

Comment: I think you're having trouble with the quantifiers. If there is an $x \in \mathbb{C}$ such that for all $y \in \mathbb{C}$, $xy = 1$, could you tell us what this $x$ is?

Comment: Also, that is not the inverse of $a + bi$. (What do you mean by "this is essentially just $a + bi$?)

Comment: What I mean, is when you split the numerator you would get a/(a^2+b^2) + bi/(a^2+b^2), but since a and b are both arbitrary numbers, a/(a^2+b^2) can just be a and bi/(a^2+b^2) can just be bi.

Comment: But I may be making an incorrect conclusion

Comment: I see what you mean, but you should only rename variables when they aren't "in use" elsewhere. When I ask "what is the inverse of $a + bi$", the answer could be written as $a + bi$, for some $a$ and $b$, but these **aren't** the same $a$ and $b$ in the question.

Comment: Yes, I know I should use a different variable. So let's say c+di for the inverse then. So since there is a number that is an element of the complex numbers (c+di) that when multiplied to a+bi gives you 1, does that mean that a+bi is unit?

Comment: Yep! But you have to prove that $c + di$ exists. I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We wish to prove: all non-zero elements of $\mathbb{C}$ are units. That is:
$$\forall z \ne 0 \in \mathbb{C}, \exists w \in \mathbb{C} \textrm{ such that } zw = 1$$

Let $z \ne 0$ be an element of $\mathbb{C}$. By definition, there are real numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $z = a + bi$. And because $z \ne 0$, we know that at least one of $a, b$ is non-zero. Therefore, $a^2 + b^2 \ne 0$, and we can consider $w = \frac{a - bi}{a^2 + b^2}$. We claim this is an inverse for $z$:
$$zw = (a + bi)\frac{a - bi}{a^2 + b^2} = \frac{a^2 + abi - abi - (bi)^2}{a^2 + b^2} = \frac{a^2 + b^2}{a^2 + b^2} = 1$$
Therefore, every non-zero element of $\mathbb{C}$ is a unit.